# Почему происходит ошибка IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Программа:

```
text = open('test.txt', 'r')
print(text.readlines()[0].strip())
print(text.readlines()[0].strip())
```

Консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(text.readlines()[0].strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: А зачем Вы пишете строку с считыванием всех строк дважды? Файл `test.txt`, кстати, не пустой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работающий вариант вашего скрипта

```
text = open('test.txt', 'r')
txt=text.readlines()[0]
print(txt.strip())
print(txt.strip())
print(txt.strip())
```

Правда глубинный смысл такой конструкции понять не могу.